# Как в готовый работающий проект внедрить Spring IoC?

Tags: java, spring, servlet

Пишу небольшой тестовый проект на java. Сначала его нужно было сделать по заданию, используя только **Servlet API**, **JSP**, **pure JDBC**. Всё получилось и работает. Теперь нужно "Внедрить **Spring IoC**". Инфы много, но нужно четкое руководство. Вроде ведь ничего сложного.. Помогите хотя бы один бин создать. Например, в слой сервисов добавить дао.
Подключил **Spring** в **pom.xml**. создал **spring-context.xml**:

```
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
       xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
       xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
       xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
       http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context.xsd">
       <bean class="ru.testScandJavaCafee.dao.CoffeeTypeDaoImpl" id="coffeeTypeDaoImpl"/>
       <bean class="ru.testScandJavaCafee.service.CoffeeTypeServiceImpl">
       <property name="coffeeTypeDao" ref="coffeeTypeDaoImpl"/>
       </bean>
</beans>
```

дао:

```
@Repository
public class CoffeeTypeDaoImpl implements CoffeeTypeDao{

    public  List<CoffeeType>  list = createListCoffeeType(new ArrayList<>());

    public List<CoffeeType> getList() {
        return list;
    }
//какой-то код
}
```

Cервис:

```
@Service
public class CoffeeTypeServiceImpl implements CoffeeTypeService {
 CoffeeTypeDao coffeeTypeDao ;
@Autowired
    public void setCoffeeTypeDao(CoffeeTypeDao coffeeTypeDao) {
        this.coffeeTypeDao = coffeeTypeDao;
    }
 @Override
    public List<CoffeeType> getListCoffeeType(String[] count) {
        List<CoffeeType> list = coffeeTypeDao.getList();
//какой-то код
 return list;
    }
}
```

До попытки перехода на спринг в сервисах было

```
CoffeeTypeDaoImpl coffeeTypeDao = new CoffeeTypeDaoImpl();
```

Что делать дальше? добавить что-то в **web.xml**?

Comment: Вроде ничего сложного, но книжки про Spring по 700 страниц.

Comment: Лучше почитать. Или же посмотреть видеороуроки например от infiniteskills 5 часов и вы будете понимать что означает аннотация '@Repository' и '@Service' как прописать в конфигах авто поиск бинов. Почему '@Autowired' не всегда срабатывает. Как правильно использовать @Resource и '@Qualifier'. Конфигурации на основе java и xml. По спрингу очень много фундаментальной информации без которой далеко не уедешь.

Answer (score 0):

Я добавляла в web.xml следующее:

```
  <context-param>
    <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
    <param-value>WEB-INF/config.xml</param-value>
  </context-param>
```

(Проверьте у себя адрес файла config.xml)